# How to get the right winner with highest card from a deck

Tags: python

I am starting with python and I am trying to code a card game where a user and computer play for 5 rounds. User and computer have to get one random card from the deck I created and the winner is the one with the highest card.

I have several problems in my code.

For example, when I create the whole deck I get this output for the "bastos" cards:

"8 de bastos", "9 de bastos", "10 de bastos" and "11 de bastos" instead of "sota de bastos", "caballo de bastos", "rey de bastos" and "as de bastos".

It only happens with "bastos" because it is my first variable in the list. But I do not know how to fix this.

Then I also have a problem with the result:

```
Tu carta es caballo de oros > Your card is King of Gold
La carta del ordenador es sota de espadas > Your card is Jokey of Spades 
Esta ronda la ha ganado el ordenador. > The computer has won this round.
```

So my programme says the computer has won when it is not ok.

I also have a similar problem with draws. My programme does not recognise any draw such as:

```
Tu carta es 5 de espadas > Your card is 5 of spaces
La carta del ordenador es 5 de copas > Computer's card is 5 of coups. 
Has ganado. > You have won.
```

This is the whole code I so far:

```
import random

print("Who will be the best out of 5 rounds?")

contador_humano = 0
contador_ordenador = 0
rondas = 0

while rondas < 5:
    rondas = rondas + 1
    print("\nRounds", rondas)

    palos = ["bastos", "copas", "espadas", "oros"]
    num = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
    baraja = []
    for n in num:
        for palo in palos:
            carta = "{} de {}".format(n,palo)
            for c in carta:
                if n == 8:
                    n = sota
                elif n == 9:
                    n = "caballo"
                elif n == 10:
                    n = "rey"
                elif n == 11:
                    n = "as"
            baraja.append(carta)
    random.shuffle(baraja)
    input("\nPress enter to shuffle.")
    print(baraja)

    carta_humano = random.choice(baraja)
    print("\nThis is your card", carta_humano)
    baraja.remove(carta_humano)
    carta_ordenador = random.choice(baraja)
    print("This is the computer card", carta_ordenador)
    
    if carta_humano > carta_ordenador:
        contador_humano += 1
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nYou have won this round.")
    elif carta_humano == carta_ordenador:
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nThis is a draw.")
    else:
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 1
        print("\nThe computer has won this round.")

    baraja.append(carta_humano)
    random.shuffle(baraja)

print("\nFinal score:", contador_humano, " - ", contador_ordenador)
            
if contador_humano > contador_ordenador:
    print("You win!")
elif contador_humano == contador_ordenador:
    print("It is a draw.")
elif contador_humano < contador_ordenador:
    print("You lose.")
```

Comment: In the logic that is supposed to transform the card names, you set the variable `n` to the new name, but then you never use `n` anywhere.  Probably remove the `for c in carta` loop and move `carta = "{} de {}".format(n,palo)` down below the name logic.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't a deck of cards have 52 cards, 13 per suit? Your suits only have 10 cards...

Comment: Regarding the result being wrong, it looks like you are comparing the cards *alphabetically* instead of by rank.

Comment: Yeah, I also have that alphabetically theory, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: @0x5453 regarding what you mention about deleting "for c in carta" and move "carta = ...", I do not completely understand where are you suggesting I should be moving the line of carta = "{} de {}".format(n,palo)

Comment: @trincot I am creating a Spanish deck, so the total number of cards is 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humans know what checking to see if a '7 of copas' > a '2 of oros' means in a card game. The computer, however, doesn't understand cards, it just knows you told it each card is a string and it evaluates the expressions to determine who wins based on the contents of the string.

To fix the problem of comparing the *entire string* for each card, "{n} de {palo}", you need to get just the num portion of each card (I assume that's what we're checking, correct me if I am wrong), which you can do by splitting the string into words (where a word is the portion of a string separated by spaces) and putting the first word from the string (since we know that is the number) into a variable which is then used for the expressions to determine who won.

I took out the block of code where you convert 8-11 to sota-as for now. I'll edit here with how to fix that when I've got it working.  For now, here is your code minus that block, I added two lines of code and edited two others, and now it gives the expected winner.

```
import random

print("Who will be the best out of 5 rounds?")

contador_humano = 0
contador_ordenador = 0
rondas = 0

while rondas < 5:
    rondas = rondas + 1
    print("\nRounds", rondas)

    palos = ["bastos", "copas", "espadas", "oros"]
    num = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
    baraja = []
    for n in num:
        for palo in palos:
            carta = "{} de {}".format(n,palo)
            baraja.append(carta)
    random.shuffle(baraja)
    input("\nPress enter to shuffle.")
    print(baraja)
    
    carta_humano = random.choice(baraja)
    print("\nThis is your card", carta_humano)
    baraja.remove(carta_humano)
    carta_ordenador = random.choice(baraja)
    print("This is the computer card", carta_ordenador)

    # get the number portion of carta_humano
    num_carta_humano = int(carta_humano.split()[0])
    
    # get the number portion of carta_ordenador
    num_carta_ordenador = int(carta_ordenador.split()[0])
        
    if num_carta_humano > num_carta_ordenador: # compare numeric portion of each card
        contador_humano += 1
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nYou have won this round.")
    elif num_carta_humano == num_carta_ordenador: # compare numeric portion of each card
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nThis is a draw.")
    else:
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 1
        print("\nThe computer has won this round.")

    baraja.append(carta_humano)
    random.shuffle(baraja)

print("\nFinal score:", contador_humano, " - ", contador_ordenador)
            
if contador_humano > contador_ordenador:
    print("You win!")
elif contador_humano == contador_ordenador:
    print("It is a draw.")
elif contador_humano < contador_ordenador:
    print("You lose.")
```

Edit:

The other half of your question was that your code to replace 8-11 with sota-as does not function as expected.

I fixed your code so that it functions the way you intended. Since the only reason you need to replace 8-11 with sota-as is for when you print out the card, I changed the code so that the card itself is not changed, but what is printed is.  I added a function at the top under the import.  When you print the deck and the cards, that function is used to replace 8-11 with sota-as, but it doesn't change the original deck or cards, just what's printed.

Here is the complete corrected code with all changes:

```
import random

def replace_num_carta(baraja, carta):
    # return the text representation of a card, replacing 8-11 with sota-as

    if int(carta.split()[0]) == 8: # if the first word in the split string is 8
        return ('sota de ' + carta.split()[-1]) # print 'sota de' concatenated to the last word of the split string
    elif int(carta.split()[0]) == 9: # if the first word in the split string is 9
        return ('caballo de ' + carta.split()[-1]) # print 'caballo de' concatenated to the last word of the split string
    elif int(carta.split()[0]) == 10: # if the first word in the split string is 10
        return ('rey de ' + carta.split()[-1]) # print 'rey de' concatenated to the last word of the split string
    elif int(carta.split()[0]) == 11: # if the first word in the split string is 11
        return ('as de ' + carta.split()[-1]) # print 'as de' concatenated to the last word of the split string
    else:
        return(carta)

print("Who will be the best out of 5 rounds?")

contador_humano = 0
contador_ordenador = 0
rondas = 0

while rondas < 5:
    rondas = rondas + 1
    print("\nRounds", rondas)

    palos = ["bastos", "copas", "espadas", "oros"]
    num = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
    baraja = []
    for n in num:
        for palo in palos:
            carta = "{} de {}".format(n,palo)
            baraja.append(carta)
    random.shuffle(baraja)
    input("\nPress enter to shuffle.")

    baraja_to_print = []
    for carta in baraja:
        baraja_to_print.append(replace_num_carta(baraja, carta)) # append the current card, after running through the function replace_num_carta

    print(baraja_to_print)

    carta_humano = random.choice(baraja)
    print("\nThis is your card " + replace_num_carta(baraja, carta_humano))
    baraja.remove(carta_humano)
    carta_ordenador = random.choice(baraja)
    print("This is the computer card " + replace_num_carta(baraja, carta_ordenador))

    # get the number portion of carta_humano
    num_carta_humano = int(carta_humano.split()[0])
    
    # get the number portion of carta_ordenador
    num_carta_ordenador = int(carta_ordenador.split()[0])
        
    if num_carta_humano > num_carta_ordenador: # compare numeric portion of each card
        contador_humano += 1
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nYou have won this round.")
    elif num_carta_humano == num_carta_ordenador: # compare numeric portion of each card
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 0
        print("\nThis is a draw.")
    else:
        contador_humano += 0
        contador_ordenador += 1
        print("\nThe computer has won this round.")

    baraja.append(carta_humano)
    random.shuffle(baraja)

print("\nFinal score:", contador_humano, " - ", contador_ordenador)
            
if contador_humano > contador_ordenador:
    print("You win!")
elif contador_humano == contador_ordenador:
    print("It is a draw.")
elif contador_humano < contador_ordenador:
    print("You lose.")
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much for all your incredible help! I am a completely newbit to python and I haven't even thought about the split method, for example! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- `for c in carta` will iterate each *character* of `carta`. That is not what you intended.
- Changing `n` *after* you have assigned a value to `carta`, will not change `carta`.
- When comparing `carta_humano > carta_ordenador`, you are comparing those strings, and so for example "rey" will be regarded greater than "as". You need to compare the numeric values of the cards.
- "sotas" must be quoted

I would suggest creating a class for a card, that will be like a tuple with rank and suit properties, and which has a `__repr__` method that will take care of generating the "nice" name. By defining it as a tuple, the order is based on the first member (rank), which is what we need.

I would also not shuffle *and* pick a random card. If you have already shuffled the deck, you can just take the last card. That is just as random as selecting a random one. You put the selected card back on the deck, but in my opinion that is overkill. There are cards enough to play 5 rounds, so don't bother putting them back. But that is just my opinion. It is not essential for your question.

The final `elif` can be just an `else` as there is only one possibility left.

Here is how it could work:

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple

class Card(namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.rank if self.rank < 8 else ["sota", "caballo", "rey", "as"][self.rank-8], self.suit)

print("Who will be the best out of 5 rounds?")

contador_humano = 0
contador_ordenador = 0

baraja = [Card(rank, suit) 
                for suit in ["bastos", "copas", "espadas", "oros"]
                for rank in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
random.shuffle(baraja)
for rondas in range(1, 6):
    input("\nPress enter to start round {}".format(rondas))
    carta_humano = baraja.pop()
    print("\nThis is your card: {}".format(carta_humano))
    carta_ordenador = baraja.pop()
    print("This is the computer card: {}".format(carta_ordenador))
    
    if carta_humano > carta_ordenador:
        contador_humano += 1
        print("\nYou have won this round.")
    elif carta_humano == carta_ordenador:
        print("\nThis is a draw.")
    else:
        contador_ordenador += 1
        print("\nThe computer has won this round.")

print("\nFinal score:", contador_humano, " - ", contador_ordenador)
            
if contador_humano > contador_ordenador:
    print("You win!")
elif contador_humano == contador_ordenador:
    print("It is a draw.")
else:
    print("You lose.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have thought about creating a Class or even different functions in my first approach, but all the solutions I could think of were kind of "difficult" to me, but the one you are offering is just really simple! Thanks!